# Is it possible to copy a local file to a remove server without using the Copy module?

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a playbook to upload a configuration file to remote servers, but the remote servers do not have python installed (which is a requirement for using modules).  I have successfully written other playbooks using the **raw** feature to avoid having to install python on the servers, but I can't find any examples in the Ansible documentation to perform a file upload using bare-bones ssh.  Is a non-module based upload possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No sure why do you use Ansible this way, but you can make a local task with `scp`:

```
- name: remote task
  raw: echo remote

- name: local scp
  local_action: command scp /path/to/localfile {{ inventory_hostname }}:/path/to/remotefile

- name: remote task
  raw: cat /path/to/remotefile
```

I usually check and install python with `raw` module and continue with Ansible core modules.

Comment: It does seem odd to work with ansible without modules, but I am prohibited from installing/updating python on these servers.  In any case, the local_action with scp worked like a charm, thanks!!!

Comment: why not just use ssh/ scp alone then?

Comment: @BradfordMedeiros I was doing more than just uploading the file, once it made it to a server, there were successive steps that needed to be completed in order.  Also, I deal with several servers (100+), so it helps to have a playbook that does the work instead of manually uploading files.

Comment: One example where I have the same need is to bootstrap AIX systems. Bootstrapping involves installing python, which in turn involves installing yum, which in turn involves copying two files to the host.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will break if you use SSH with a password, as happens when bootstrapping a system and the public keys aren't yet installed.

Comment: @KevinKeane you can use `sshpass -p <passwd> ssh -p port user@hostname` then. As we are running locally sshpass needs to be installed on the local machine

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not always be applicable, but as long as you are allowed to put the files on some kind of Web or so server, and as long as curl or wget or similar are installed on the remote system, you can use those tools to download your files within the raw block.